# How to upgrade Sealed Secrets for Kubernetes without causing an outage

Tags: kubernetes

Today I go to update some sealed env variables (aka secrets) and notice that the `sealed-secrets-controller` pod is down.  It is stuck trying to get its image.

`Back-off pulling image "quay.io/bitnami/sealed-secrets-controller:v0.8.1"`

Looks like I am running an old version, the latest is `v0.18.1`.  So my question is, how exactly do I upgrade to the latest version without causing an outage.  An outage would be that my pods are not able to obtain their secrets.  My current k8s version is `v1.21.11`, in case that matters.

I suspect an outage can occur if for example the certificate gets changed during the upgrade.  I was not able to find an upgrade guide online.

The only thing I can think of would be to delete the currently installed Sealed Secrets pod, install the new one using the controller.yml for v0.18.1, restart one of my pods, verify that it works, if not, re-generate the encrypted secrets, apply them, restart my pod, hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading is the same as installing. But you should read the release notes for any breaking changes.

Kubernetes handles the upgrade to cause no outages.

1. Read the release notes and prepare for potential changes.
2. Download the release yamls into a sealed-secrets directory.
3. Apply the upgrade `kubectl apply -f sealed-secrets`

Or use the helm chart.